# Icefaces How to add multiple calls in JavascriptContext?

Tags: javascript, call, icefaces

To run multiple calls I know i can do this:

```
String call1 = "doSomething1();";
String call2 = "doSomething2();";
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(currentInstance, call1 + call2);
```

But i want to add calls independently, something like this:

```
String call1 = "doSomething1();";
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(currentInstance, call1);
...
String call2 = "doSomething2();";
JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(currentInstance, call2);
```

When I do this, it doesn't work. Any thought?